# How do I get my sound working?

Tags: fedora, audio

I've managed to get as far as getting the following:

I used the following commands as suggested:

```
$ dmesg | egrep -i "(alsa|sound)"
    [    4.756399] input: HDA Intel PCH Mic as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input14
    [    4.756467] input: HDA Intel PCH Headphone as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input15
```

-

```
$ dmesg | egrep -i "alsa|audio|sound|snd"
[    0.412466] ACPI: Added _OSI(Linux-Lenovo-NV-HDMI-Audio)
[    4.727453] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1f.3: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    4.727633] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1f.3: Linked as a consumer to 0000:00:02.0
[    4.727669] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1f.3: bound 0000:00:02.0 (ops i915_audio_component_bind_ops [i915])
[    4.763584] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0: autoconfig for ALC1220: line_outs=1 (0x1b/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0) type:speaker
[    4.763585] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0:    speaker_outs=0 (0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0)
[    4.763585] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0:    hp_outs=1 (0x14/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0)
[    4.763586] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0:    mono: mono_out=0x0
[    4.763586] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0:    dig-out=0x1e/0x0
[    4.763587] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0:    inputs:
[    4.763588] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0:      Mic=0x19
[    4.763588] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0:      Internal Mic=0x12
[    4.776194] input: HDA Intel PCH Mic as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input11
[    4.776260] input: HDA Intel PCH Headphone as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input12
```

-

```
$ lspci | egrep -i "audio|sound|snd"
    00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH cAVS (rev 10)
```

-

```
$ lsmod | egrep -i "alsa|audio|sound|snd"
    snd_soc_skl           118784  0
    snd_soc_hdac_hda       24576  1 snd_soc_skl
    snd_hda_ext_core       32768  2 snd_soc_hdac_hda,snd_soc_skl
    snd_soc_skl_ipc        73728  1 snd_soc_skl
    snd_soc_sst_ipc        20480  1 snd_soc_skl_ipc
    snd_hda_codec_realtek   126976  1
    snd_soc_sst_dsp        40960  1 snd_soc_skl_ipc
    snd_soc_acpi_intel_match    28672  1 snd_soc_skl
    snd_soc_acpi           16384  2 snd_soc_acpi_intel_match,snd_soc_skl
    snd_hda_codec_generic    90112  1 snd_hda_codec_realtek
    snd_soc_core          270336  2 snd_soc_hdac_hda,snd_soc_skl
    ledtrig_audio          16384  2 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_realtek
    snd_compress           28672  1 snd_soc_core
    ac97_bus               16384  1 snd_soc_core
    snd_pcm_dmaengine      16384  1 snd_soc_core
    snd_hda_intel          45056  4
    snd_hda_codec         155648  4 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_soc_hdac_hda
    snd_hda_core           98304  7 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_ext_core,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_soc_hdac_hda,snd_soc_skl
    snd_hwdep              16384  1 snd_hda_codec
    snd_seq                86016  0
    snd_seq_device         16384  1 snd_seq
    snd_pcm               118784  7 snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_ext_core,snd_hda_codec,snd_soc_core,snd_soc_skl,snd_hda_core,snd_pcm_dmaengine
    snd_timer              40960  2 snd_seq,snd_pcm
    snd                    94208  19 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_seq,snd_seq_device,snd_hwdep,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_timer,snd_compress,snd_soc_core,snd_pcm
    soundcore              16384  1 snd
```

The two  choices I have for play back are "Speakers - Built-In-Audio" and "Digital Output (S/PDIF) - Built-In Audio"

The windows version of my driver:

```
Realtek Audio Driver Version 6.0.1.8612
```

Comment: Try `dmesg | egrep -i "alsa|audio|sound|snd"`. Also `lspci | egrep -i "audio|sound|snd"`, and  `lsmod | egrep -i "alsa|audio|sound|snd"`

Comment: Updated with the outputs of your suggested commands.

Answer (score 0):

this article helped me:
https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/How_to_debug_sound_problems

Being more specific, this command:

```
dnf|yum remove alsa-plugins-pulseaudio
```

Notice that you have to choose either dnf or yum when running the command.

Comment: since the pipe symbol (`|`) is a functional element in UNIX, where you appear to have intended it to be a logical "or", I would recommend that you rewrite the Answer slightly to indicate that you could use one of the two commands.

Comment: Well if you think its really necessary, ok